# How to implement Trapezoidal method in PHP?

Tags: php, algorithm

> Z = TRAPZ(X,Y) computes the integral
>   of Y with respect to X using
>       the trapezoidal method.

[`TRAPZ`](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/trapz.html) is an existing function in MATLAB, but how to implement it in PHP?

Answer (score 2):

hey, what about wikipedia? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule here is great explanation and even code samples.